# Shinobi Chart got "No x axis found for series at index 0" error

Tags: ios, charts, shinobi

I'm using ShinobiChart in my App, I set the numberOfSeries always be 1:

> - -(int)numberOfSeriesInSChart:(ShinobiChart*)chart{
>     return 1;
>     }

and I used SChartDateTimeAxis for the xAxis :

> SChartDateTimeAxis *xAxis = [[SChartDateTimeAxis alloc] init];
>      xAxis.labelFormatter = labelFormatter;
>      xAxis.allowPanningOutOfDefaultRange = NO;
>      xAxis.style.majorGridLineStyle.showMajorGridLines = NO;
>     xAxis.style.majorTickStyle.showTicks = YES;
>      xAxis.allowPanningOutOfMaxRange = YES;
>     self.lineChart.xAxis = xAxis;

anyone got the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

After adding the axis to the lineChart, you will need to tell the chart to redraw with:

```
[self.lineChart redrawChart];
```